# Is it bad to have just 1 chunk size in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I have to process a file which has records with same ID and different dates. If a specific ID has multiple records with the different dates, it has to sum all of it. Currently, my solution is writing by one chunk and and letting SQL query to do the summation part because I don't have a way to know if multiple entries of same ID are in the same chunk. Is there a huge performance effect of doing it this way especially that I am working on 100k worth of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a huge performance effect of doing it this way especially that I am working on 100k worth of data?

Yes, this could impact the performance of your step since each item will be processed in its own transaction. With 100k you would have 100k transactions, whereas if chunk-size=1000 for example, you would have only 100 transactions.

The chunk-oriented processing model is not really suitable to what you are trying to do, as items with the same ID could span different chunks. A common technique for this kind of requirement is to load your data in a temporary table (which could be a very fast step if done against sqlite for example) and then run your aggregation SQL query against that table.